# Which Stack Exchange site should I ask a question about Laundry Detergent on?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, I'd like to ask a question about the difference between "HE", "HE Turbo", and "HE Turbo clean", which have appeared successively over the years, and are very confusing in actual meaning.

(The Images are too big, see bottom.)

I'm looking for (a) the practical (wash performance) difference, and (b) the chemical/technical differences.

It seems like it's just marketing B.S., and I wouldn't be surprised if it was the idea of a corporate executive who wanted to "fix" some issue.

Is there anywhere on Stack Exchange where can I ask the question?

[I can find pages mentioning "laundry detergent" on several sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22laundry%20detergent%22%20site%3Astackexchange.com):

- *Travel* Stack Exchange site (["Non-biological laundry detergent available in the US?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/non-biological-laundry-detergent-available-in-the-us))
- *Skeptics* Stack Exchange (["Are some laundry detergents better than others?"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/are-some-laundry-detergents-better-than-others), ["Are laundry detergent and fabric softener fumes dangerous to human health?"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12461/are-laundry-detergent-and-fabric-softener-fumes-dangerous-to-human-health))
- Parenting Stack Exchange site (["What is a good baby laundry detergent that is not tested on animals?"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-is-a-good-baby-laundry-detergent-that-is-not-tested-on-animals))
- Everyday Chemistry Stack Exchange site (["Do dishwashing detergent and stain remover powder/stick have the similar ability to remove collar rings?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/do-dishwashing-detergent-and-stain-remover-powder-stick-have-the-similar-ability), ["Do various soaps work better when dissolved/used in different water temperatures?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/do-various-soaps-work-better-when-dissolved-used-in-different-water-temperatures))
- User Experience Stack Exchange site (["Is duping the consumer really a good business practice?"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/is-duping-the-consumer-really-a-good-business-practice))

Personally, I think *Skeptics* & *Everyday Chemistry* are the two most plausible candidates, because both go into technical detail. The deceptive design practices mentioned in the User Experience Stack Exchange happen to confirm my intuition that it's at least partly a marketing issue (yay confirmation bias!).

*Yes, I'm "overthinking" laundry detergent. I don't actually think that's a bad thing.*

---

This [image] [became](http://news.tide.com/press-release/tide-corporate/tide-introduces-new-standard-he-detergents%E2%80%94he-turbo-clean) this:
[image: "HE TURBO CLEAN"]

Comment: Do note that not all questions have a home somewhere on some Stack Exchange site.  Some questions are just off-topic on every site -- so don't start from the premise/assumption that every question will necessarily be OK somewhere, and it's just a matter of figuring out where.  Anyway, have you read the help center pages on each site you mentioned?  They each have a page that describes what is on-topic there.

Comment: Go to Area 51 and propose laundry.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: (For clarity: the above is a joke. Please *don't* do that!)

Comment: This really feels like a question for the sales and marketing division of the appropriate company. That's why it *doesn't* feel like a good question on any of the SE sites.

Comment: Is this question spam? I think this question is spam. This is spam, isn't it?  This question is spam.  Damn you, HE Turbo clean!

Comment: @D.W. I still wasn't sure, and figured that the best idea was to ask. Therefore, others can see the answer. Such is the spirit of StackExchange, is it not?

Comment: @MichaelT I want the truth, the technical reasoning, which is *precisely* why I *wouldn't* ask the sales and marketing division of any company.

Comment: @AlexanderRiccio can anyone actually answer that question without sitting down with a chemistry lab and identifying all of the different chemicals, and if there is any difference in ratio or composition and then analyzing and hypothesizing about what effect this may have on the functionality of the product? Everything else would be a guess based on nothing more than package labeling and rumor.

Comment: @MichaelT aside from the fact that users sometimes actually *do* run lab-style experiments (see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/cooling-a-cup-of-coffee-with-help-of-a-spoon ), I imagine that a soap engineer/scientist could provide insight, from knowing somebody involved with the development of said detergent, or actually being themselves involved in it. Other possibilities include: Someone else who works at P&G, someone like a scientist at Consumer Reports, etc...

Comment: If you believe it would be a good question somewhere - ask there.  I gave you my reasoning that it wouldn't be a question that would be answerable except by someone with inside knowledge (and thus likely under NDA). Asking consumer reports directly would probably be your best option IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the products claim to save time, water, and energy, perhaps you could ask your question on [Sustainable Living](//sustainability.stackexchange.com/).